# Given p and q of DSA how do you show they are prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, dsa

I am given

```
p = 4916335901 
q = 88903
```

and am asked to show these are prime as well as `q|(p-1)` in DSA.

I am unsure on how to do this, what does `q|(p-1)` mean exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am given $p = 4916335901$, $q = 88903$ and am asked to show these are prime

To check whether a given integer $n$ is prime you have to check whether it is only divisible by $1$ and $n$, i.e., that it is not a composite integer. If you are given such an integer you can either [factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) the given integer, use [primality tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) to check for primality or in case of such small numbers just ask [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+prime+4916335901). In your case, both $p$ and $q$ are indeed prime, and your given $p$ is of the form $p=k\cdot q +1$. Most often one encounters the use of $k=2$, so called [safe primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime) in cryptography. You can [generate such primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) even in the size for cryptographic purposes efficiently.

> as well as $q|(p-1)$ in DSA.

The notation $a|b$ means that $a$ evenly divides $b$, i.e., $b$ divided by $a$ gives a remainder of zero. This is easy to check by computing $\frac{4916335901-1}{88903}=55300$, so yes $q|(p-1)$.

Using a prime of the form $p=k\cdot q+1$ with small $k$, you know that when you are working in ${\mathbb Z}_p^*$ (which has order $p-1$) that you have a cyclic subgroup of prime order $q$.